# how to use if condition with web_reg_find

Tags: loadrunner

how to incorporate if condition with **web_reg_find**

For instance

```
if
{

web_reg_find("Search=Body", "Text=Launch Title",    LAST);
 //----Passes
    {
  printf("%d\n", login successful);  /* user will login
}
 }

Else 
{

printf("%d\n", login not successful);  /* user will not login

}
```

end of code

Comment: Can you reformat your question body? It is not clear where the code starts and ends.

Comment: Your example will not work as intended.  web_reg_find is a service function and will not have a value until the page loads.   Please view the example in the help file and the self paced training material for Loadrunner

Comment: Thanks for the input, Even if so once the page loads and finds the intended texts need to incorporate the if condition so that based on the web_reg_find if condition should work.....

Comment: Covered in online help, standard product training and self paced training

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use the savecount attribute of the web reg find function, where it will save how many times it found the text on the page.

```
web_reg_find("Text=Welcome","SaveCount=Welcome_Count",LAST );
.........
......
if (atoi(lr_eval_string("{Welcome_Count}")) > 0){
        lr_output_message("Login successful.");
  }

 else{
     lr_error_message("Login failed");
     return(0);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Action()
{
    int returncode;

    lr_continue_on_error(1);

    web_reg_find("Search=Body", "Text=Launch Title",    LAST);

returncode = web_url("<YOUR URL>",
                 [...]

    if (returncode!=LR_PASS)
        {
        lr_error_message ("user will not login");
        return -1 // Script abort
        }
    else    
        {
        lr_output_message ("user will login");
        }

    lr_continue_on_error(0);
```

This works

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use **SaveCount** attribute in **web_reg_find** function, which will save the counts of your text present in the request page and then you can easily use if else function

```
lr_start_transaction("Login");

web_reg_find("Search=Body", "Text=Launch Title","SaveCount=LaunchTitle_Count", LAST);
//your request comes here

if (atoi(lr_eval_string("{LaunchTitle_Count}")) >= 1)
{
    lr_output_message("Login Successful");
    lr_end_transaction("Login",LR_PASS);
}

 else
{
   lr_error_message("Login Failed");
   lr_end_transaction("Login",LR_FAIL);
}
```